# Can't enable a Nginx dynamic module

Tags: nginx

I've installed Nginx on a server (Ubuntu) from source. Now I need to enable an additional nginx dymanic module.
I tried this:

```
./configure --with-ngx_http_image_filter_module
make
make install
```

The `.so` file appears in the `/modules` folder.

Then I added below line to `nginx.conf`:

```
load_module /modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;
```

and restarted the service.

After that, when I execute `nginx -V` it only displays few modules:

```
--with-http_v2_module --with-pcre
```

and there's no `ngx_http_image_filter_module.so` among them.

Could you please help me if I a missing anything?

Comment: are you sure about the path? /modules is not a standard path

Comment: My nginx config is here

/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

The modules directory is in the /usr/local/nginx folder (/usr/local/nginx/modules). 

As far as I see the server checks the paths 
relatively to /usr/local/nginx. 
So in my case /modules seems a correct path. 

One way or the other, what is the standard path? How to know what directory the server actually asks for modules?

Comment: I've just even tried to reset the modules folder path with  

./configure --modules-path=/modules 

It went without any errors or notifications and the nginx service starts properly, but nothing's changed about modules. 

The nginx -V responce is: 
nginx version: nginx/1.25.4
built by gcc 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2)
configure arguments: --with-http_v2_module --with-pcre

Even though, there's no http_v2_module.so or something like this in the modules directory. ngx_http_image_filter_module.so is the only file located in there. 
Is that ok?

Comment: Another thing which looks strange to me is how short the responce to nginx -V is. It contains only OS and Nginx versions and few configure agruments. Shouldn't it contain at least this "--modules-path=/modules" I used before?

Comment: I believe there may have been a misunderstanding. It seems that the intended path is not "/path", but rather "path/". Is there a folder named "modules" located under the root directory? If not, then the module path should be "/usr/local/nginx/modules" and the "module name" folder should be correct. From the current perspective, it appears that you are stating that the "modules" folder is located directly under the root directory.

Comment: I uninstalled and installed Nginx from scratch.
Here is the path to the conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
The modules folder is /etc/nginx/modules/
I enabled a module by using './configure --with-<module_name>' followed by 'make' and 'make install' commands. 
/etc/nginx is not default path, so the module 'so'-file was created in the '/usr/local/nginx/module/' folder, so I moved it to '/etc/nginx/modules/'. 

Then, I add 'load_module /modules/<module_name>;' to the config file.

When I restart the service then I get this:

Comment: Mar 20 09:20:14 linux systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: nginx init.d dash script for Ubuntu or other *nix..
Mar 20 09:20:14 linux systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 20 09:20:14 linux systemd[1]: Reload failed for LSB: nginx init.d dash script for Ubuntu or other *nix..
Mar 20 09:20:14 linux nginx[10538]: nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/usr/local/nginx/module/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so" failed (/usr/local/nginx/module/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or direc>

Comment: Mar 20 09:20:14 linux nginx[10538]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Mar 20 09:22:24 linux systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: nginx init.d dash script for Ubuntu or other *nix..
Mar 20 09:22:24 linux nginx[10554]: nginx: [emerg] dlopen() "/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so" failed (/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf>

Comment: Mar 20 09:22:24 linux nginx[10554]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Mar 20 09:22:24 linux systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 20 09:22:24 linux systemd[1]: Reload failed for LSB: nginx init.d dash script for Ubuntu or other *nix..

Comment: So, you're definetely right about paths, but I can't understand why doesn't it use the path I put into the config. 
I even reset the default path to the modules by using this:
'./configure --modules-path=/etc/nginx/modules   make    make install', but nothing has changed.

Comment: Instead of spamming here, i suggest to join the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152140/questions-1156451)

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't join the chat, because of this:
'You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here'.

Comment: then use find / -name ngx_http_image_filter_module.so

Comment: and please just to clean up the comment section, always put requests info as an edit to your question. if done please remove the Comments with the responses.

Comment: in addition, you usually dont need to compile it on your own. for debian and ubuntu the nginx reposity delivers the package "libnginx-mod-http-image-filter" which only need to be installed with apt(-get)